# How to handle ID's within XDevComboBox/ RapidClipse codebuilder?

Tags: java, vaadin, rapidclipse

Inside a fieldgroup I would like to use a dropdown field `XDevComboBox` for modifying a value.
The combobox get filled by a database table (works fine).
The table has two fields, an id and a text-value.
The textvalue should be visible and possible to select in the combobox.
I am able to select the textvalue.

But in the code behind I need the id related to the textvalue.

> Is there a way to handle this with build in functions of rapidclipse?